# NVIM - can't unmap escape key

Tags: vim, neovim

I can unmap escape key from insert mode. When I call `:iunmap <Esc>` it says `E31: No such mapping`.

**But** when I call `:imap <Esc>` it says:

```
i <Esc> *@pumvisible() ? '<C-E>' : '<C-R>=<SNR>110_FlushBuffer()<CR><Esc>'
```

so it seems that in the end there is something on ESC.

Probably [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) plugin messed something up.

I wanted to remap ESC to 2xESC because when there is deoplete (its same as youcompleteme) cloud ESC key closes the cloud, so I have to press ESC twice to exit insert mode.

Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> But when I call `:imap <Esc>` it says:
>
> `i <Esc> *@pumvisible() ? '<C-E>' : '<C-R>=<SNR>110_FlushBuffer()<CR><Esc>'`

The `@` indicates a *buffer-local* mapping (created with `:inoremap <buffer> <Esc> ...`).

It turns out that `:unmap` *also* takes a `<buffer>` modifier. So in this case:

```
:unmap <buffer> <Esc>
```

Before doing that, you can see which plugin set the mapping:

```
:verbose map <Esc>
```